# Why does UINavigationBar Image have bad quality?

Tags: objective-c

I have picked a menu image that I want to implement on the navigation bar. The image is 120x92 pixels and the resolution is 72.

```
UIImage *menu = [self imageWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu.png"] convertToSize:CGSizeMake(45, 34.5)]; 
   self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.image = menu;
```

The problem is that the menu image seems very blurry. What might be the reason/s for bad image quality? How can I fix it? Thank you!

Comment: You've created a blurry image maybe?

Comment: 45x34.5 should have a nice image if 120x92 does, right? Plus when it is UIImageView it looks fine. I have the same image issue with annotationViews as well. Frustrating.